# How to use a Riverpod provider in initState

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-listview, flutter-state, flutter-riverpod

I use Riverpod as state management in my web app. I am trying to build an AppBar that scrolls automatically to certain parts of a ListView.

I created a ScrollController as a provider for this purpose.

```
final scrollControllerProvider = StateProvider<ScrollController?>((ref) => ScrollController());
```

To scroll, I use `.animateTo` from the AppBar actions.

```
ref.read(scrollControllerProvider)!.animateTo(
  0,
  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  curve: Curves.easeInOut,
);
```

The scrolling works, but it throws an exception

```
The provided ScrollController is currently attached to more than one ScrollPosition.
```

I have read that I should be using a StatefulWidget. However, using a ConsumerStatefulWidget I can't create the ScrollController using Riverpod, because I need to initiate it in `initState()` and I can't access to a provider from it. Is possible to have these two elements together?

Comment: Why do use are use approach with providing `ScrollController`? They need uniq for each widget and should store locally.

Comment: @fartem Is there an alternative approach that I can use?

Comment: you can use consumerStatefulWidget, or stateful widget wih consumer as its child

Comment: @SayyidJ I have tried that, I can't access the providers in the initState method

Answer (score 2):

I thimk a solution is to use ref.read(...) In the init method. It would not update the view and take the correct valute.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollController` is a `ChangeNotifier` class, instead of `StateProvider`, use `ChangeNotifierProvider`, keep in mind if you can't attach it to multiple scrollable.

```
final myScrollControllerProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => ScrollController());
```

maybe we can make it into new class, create a like `forceDispose()` method :

```
class MyScrollController extends ScrollController {
  void forceDispose(){
    this.dispose();
  }
}
```

but since i am not sure how you use this, and where you will dispose it in some state,either we can't initialize it in some initState(), lets just leave the provider autoDispose its self:

```
 final myScrollControllerProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider.autoDispose((ref) => ScrollController());
```

i test it, i create New Consumer to Imitate Another Widget, but you must sure the actuall scrollable still mounted :

```
class MyWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ref) {
    final sc = ref.watch(myScrollControllerProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Consumer(
                builder: (BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref, Widget? _) {
                  final scFromAnotherWidget = ref.watch(myScrollControllerProvider);
                  return TextButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        scFromAnotherWidget.jumpTo(sc.offset + 30);
                      },
                      child: const Text("Animate to"));
                },
              ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const NewScreen()));
                  },
                  child: const Text("Navigate to brand new Screen"))
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              controller: sc,
              itemCount: 100,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text('$index'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const NewScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MyWidget()));
            },
            child: const Text('Back to My Widget')),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: the controller is the provider, I need to access it from initState

Comment: sorry i was misunderstand before, but scroll controller is use localy, its useless to use it as global variable and use everywhere. its only can attach and listen to single scrollable, and you need to dispose it localy to avoid memory leaks. if you could point me the reason why you need to use provider to hold scroll controller, maybe i can help with in spesific case

Comment: I need to store it globally because I want to access the scrolling from a different widget. I explain the whole situation better in this other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74956984/flutter-push-a-new-page-and-scroll-down-to-certain-widget because I was trying with a different approach with GlobalKeys instead

Comment: i edited the answer maybe can help you in your case?

Answer (score 0):

You have access to `ref` inside any function that resides in the `ConsumerStatefulWidget`. So, you can simply call your provider in `initState()` function and it should behave normally

```
...
  class _MyClassState extends ConsumerState<MyClass> {

  late ScrollController _scrollController;
  
  @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _scrollController = ref.read(scrollControllerProvider); // Doesn't throw error
    }
...
```

Comment: It does throw an error: `The argument type 'StateProvider<ScrollController?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderListenable<ScrollController>'.`

Comment: Correction: it does not throw an error if used with `!`, but the Riverpod documentation says the watch method should not be used in initState(). I used read instead, but now the controller goes scrolls down to the required position and then goes up again.

Comment: You cannot use ref.watch in init method

Comment: Sure. But nothing is stopping you from using ref.read as well, right? I have edited my answer to ref.read now